# cakephp pagination with advance Filter

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination

I am using cake php scroll pagination to paging products.
I am using group of check boxes in view part to set manual condition by user to paginate.
I used following code to set a condition after ajax request.

```
class SearchController  extends AppController {
public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Session','Paginator','Js' => 'Jquery');
public $components = array('RequestHandler','Session','Cookie','Paginator');
public function index() {
$this->loadModel("Bangsworkinghrs");
$agetworkinghrs = $this->Bangsworkinghrs->getworkinghrs();
$this->set('agetworkinghrs', $agetworkinghrs);  
$this->loadModel("Gig");
    $options = array('Gig.subcategory' => 'Logo Design');
    if(!empty($this->request->data['filter']['workinghrs'])) {
        $options = array('Gig.subcategory' => 'Logo');
    }
    $this->Paginator->settings = $options;
    $agetGigsItem = $this->Paginator->paginate('Gig', $options);
    $this->set('agetGigsItem', $agetGigsItem);   

}
}
```

via this code i am able to change condition of paging but server explodes only default 20 records next records is not exploding by server and there is no error message my cakephp version is 2.6.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#filter').submit();` try submit form and remove ajax refresh data from your jquery part replace filter with your form name.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing 'page' and 'limit' attribute of Cakephp default pagination.

In your options array you need to pass page number and no of records per page.

Something like this but in dynamic way.

`$options = array('conditions' => array('Gig.subcategory' => 'Logo Design'),'page'=>2,'limit'=>20);`

Comment: but in scroll pagination i dont think i need it because  it is working if i didnt place second condition

Answer (score 0):

```
using action="get" in the form where $this->request->query['filter']['workinghrs'] data is come.
```

Coding:

```
public $paginate = array(
        'limit' => 20
    );

public function index() 
{
    $this->loadModel("Gig");
    $options = array('Gig.subcategory' => 'Logo Design');
    if(!empty($this->request->query['filter']['workinghrs'])) {
        $options = array('Gig.subcategory' => 'Vector Design');
    }
    $this->Paginator->settings = $options;
    $agetGigsItem = $this->Paginator->paginate('Gig', $options);
    $this->set('agetGigsItem', $agetGigsItem);    
}
```

Comment: i also tried same but after set condition it explode only 20 records next records which comes after page scroll is not working i want pagination same like flipkart or jabong where user can set manual pagination condition.